# load json data into js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am learning how to load json data into .js file.  I have created a employee.json file.  I saved my js and json file and on the desktop.  What I trying to do is to put all the id in json files into an array in the js.  I do not know what could be wrong.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>JSON with jQuery</title>
    </head>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <h1><h2>
  <script src = "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var res = [];
      $.ajax({
          url: 'employee.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
              $(data.people).each(function(index, value) {
                 res.push(value.id);
              });
          }
      });

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.toString();
  </script>

</body>
</html>

{
"person": [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "firstName" : "Lokesh"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "firstName" : "bryant"
    }
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "firstName" : "kobe"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: In the json you have person object but you used people object in the each iterator.Any Reason???

Comment: `data.people` or `data.person`

Comment: setup a localhost and do the same.

Comment: comma is missing in your json file after id 2

Comment: I changed it but it still does not work

Answer (score 4):

- **Error 1:** Typing error. `<script src = "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You mistyped the `src` of the script, accidentally adding another another `<script>` start tag.
- **Error 2:** Misplaced statement. `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.toString();` should be placed in the `success` callback function, so it will be executed only after the server responds. If it executes prematurely, `res` will still be `[]`.
- **Error 3:** `type: 'GET'` should be `method: 'GET'`, according to the docs (though 'GET' is default so you don't need to explicitly write this).

Use this:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<h1><h2>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var res = [];
      $.ajax({
          url: 'employee.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          method: 'get',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
              $(data.people).each(function(index, value) {
                 res.push(value.id);
              });
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.toString();
          }
      });


  </script>
```

Comment: Thank u Kyle for the response.  I changed in the way as your suggestion and I change person to people which is another typo, but it is still not right.  Did you miss something here?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. Perhaps you should use '/employee.json' (begin with slash to make path absolute). Also, I don't know where you are hosting this. A cross-origin request could also be the problem. The Same Origin Policy also has special rules for /localhost/ and file:// URLs (which I forgot), so if you are hosting from localhost there, you should look into those restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the local json to read. it gives cross origin request failure. so deploy both the files (html and json) into a we server and execute. or place the json data onto some web url(http://somesite/myjson) and then request that url and see.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the JSON shouldn't be existed as in physical "file". It has to be generated by a backend language / web service etc. The JSON tags inside a manually created "file" have high chance of data invalidity upon parsing.

### Solution

Use a Web Service to generate valid JSON output. And from Javascript end, use:

```
JSON.stringify( data );
```